# Get only a filter value ols:PROPERTIES from this API response

Tags: geoserver, geojson, wfs

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ols:ols&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=1&format_options=application/json&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, POINT (90.411987 23.829202))'
```

This is my Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ols="ols" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd ols http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=ols%3Aols">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <ols:ols fid="ols.291">
            <ols:the_geom>
                <gml:MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                    <gml:polygonMember>
                        <gml:Polygon>
                            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">90.43163284,23.81512401,3.05 90.43166878,23.81508952,0 90.43166937,23.81508895,0 90.43166944,23.81508889,0 90.43166944,23.81508889,0 90.5167,23.73581667,3.05 90.49764888,23.72308208,0 90.47563481,23.70849927,3.05 90.41959167,23.80706111,0 90.4160188,23.81325469,0 90.41601767,23.81325665,0 90.41601288,23.81326496,0 90.40658333,23.82961111,3.05 90.40745941,23.83020386,0 90.40929888,23.83144851,0 90.41226339,23.83343377,3.05 90.43147799,23.81527124,0 90.43156363,23.8151903,0 90.43160238,23.81515323,0 90.43163284,23.81512401,3.05</gml:coordinates>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        </gml:Polygon>
                    </gml:polygonMember>
                </gml:MultiPolygon>
            </ols:the_geom>
            <ols:AREA>136335.2112</ols:AREA>
            <ols:PERIMETER>2097.38593</ols:PERIMETER>
            <ols:PROPERTIES>S3220</ols:PROPERTIES>
        </ols:ols>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

How can I get `ols:PROPERTIES`  in JSON

Comment: please stop tagging your questions `geoserver-rest-api`, that is for the administrative control of GeoServer and has nothing to do with WFS

Comment: You need to request a format that is supported by the version of WFS you are using, using the correct parameter.  For WFS 1.0.0 you should use `outputFormat`, not doing so gives you the default output which is GML2.

Answer (score 2):

I need to add **propertyName** in the **parameter**  like the old parameter list is

```
service:WFS
version:1.0.0
request:GetFeature
typeName:ols:ols
srsName:EPSG:4326
maxFeatures:1
format_options:application/json
cql_filter:INTERSECTS(the_geom, POINT (90.411987 23.829202))
```

new parameter list is :

```
    service:WFS
version:1.0.0
request:GetFeature
typeName:ols:ols
srsName:EPSG:4326
maxFeatures:1
format_options:application/json
cql_filter:INTERSECTS(the_geom, POINT (90.411987 23.829202))
propertyName:PROPERTIES
```